# Which were the first browser versions to support scrollbar styling

Tags: html, css

I'm a distance diploma student and a question that came up was did Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer/Edge support scrollbar styling and if each of them did, which were the first versions of them to do so, did they require a webkit, and do they still require one, if not which version did they stop? I googled it but haven't been able t find anything and for once W3C has failed me, although my googling has informed me that that's because scrollbar styling is an invention of microsoft and hasn't been officially recognised by W3C. I figured that rather than stumble blindly I'd ask here, seeing as I usually get really good answers, or at least pointed in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE5.5 was the first browser to support basic styling for the scrollbars. However, it was limited just to the colors. Using the scrollbar-face-color property, you could change their display color. 
source:https://www.devstreak.com/scrollbar-styling-using-css-jquery/

A common method of altering the look of the scrollbar in Web pages is to use CSS directives to change the scrollbar colors. These are non-standard and supported only by Microsoft Internet Explorer versions 5.x or higher and Opera. all other browsers introduced scrollbar styling through webkit 
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrollbar

Comment: Do you know which version of chrome and firefox first supported it?

Comment: don't know about firefox but chrome first supported in Version 2.0.172 in 2009-05-24 with WebKit engin 530 | source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history and https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/